# GET request with postman works, while with PHP cURL I get an empty string

Tags: php, api, curl, postman, php-curl

I'm trying to get some data out of an API with GET request.
I get everything done with Postman, but when I'm trying the exact same thing from PHP cURL I only get an empty string.

I've looked for similar questions and only found that in some sites it helps adding user-agent header. I've added it and the response is the same - empty string.
please help me.

[image]

Comment: Postman has the option of generating the PHP cURL code for you - have you tried using it and comparing it to your code to see if an option is missing or something is not defined in the same way?

Comment: Thank you @El_Vanja . that solves it for me. I wrote the AuthToken header incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just wrote the 'AuthToken' incorrectly.
should be
'AuthToken: ' . $token